# Why is this space Hilbert

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This is more or less a question about a technical detail in Evan's PDEs Chapter 6 problem 4. Let $\Omega$ be an open, connected, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary. Consider the subspace $H=\{u\in H^1(\Omega): \int_{\Omega} u\,\text{d}x=0\}$ with the inner product $\langle u,v\rangle_H:=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,\text{d}x$. It is easy to see that this is indeed an inner product (relying heavily on the connectedness hypothesis). However I would like to go further and see that it is a Hilbert space.

I start with a Cauchy sequence $\{u_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ in $H$, which by definition means that $\int_{\Omega}\lvert \nabla(u_m-u_n)\rvert^2\,\text{d}x\to 0$ as $m,n\to\infty$. Now I want to demonstrate that this sequence has a limit and I feel like I should be using Fatou's lemma or something, but I have gotten nowhere and I'm trying to interchange these lim infs and (weak) gradients and it seems super sketchy. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Do you know how to show that $H^1$ itself is complete?

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. It is clear by $L^2$ completeness that the gradient $\nabla u_m$ has a limit. I'm not sure how to show that $\{u_m\}$ itself is convergent or even Cauchy in $L^2$.

Comment: Can you use the Poincare inequality?

Comment: That only holds on $H_0^1(\Omega)$. In fact it is false on $H^1(\Omega)$, for instance using the function $v\equiv 1$.

Comment: Look at Evans 5.8.1 Theorem 1. This is a generalization of the result you are citing.

Comment: Oh duh. That makes a lot of sense. I think I see exactly what to do.

Comment: In the phrase "Hilbert space" the word "Hilbert" is not an adjective; rather "Hilbert space" is a compound noun. Thus, some would say that many spaces are Hilbert spaces, but no space is Hilbert; i.e. no space is the man who set his famous list of problems in 1900 and died in 1943.

Comment: I suppose you're right, but even in academic papers people say things like "This sequence is Cauchy" as opposed to saying "this is a Cauchy sequence", which is an instance of the same usage issue you are pointing out.